# How to GET responde status code from get request?

Tags: python, url, get, endpoint

Hi I am very new to python programming. Here I'm trying to write a python script which will get a status code using GET request. I can able to do it for single URL but how to do it for multiple URL's in a single script.
Here is the basic code I have written which will get response code from a url.

```
import requests
import json
import jsonpath

#API URL
url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"

#Send Get Request
response = requests.get(url)
if response:
    print('Response OK')
else:
    print('Response Failed')

# Display Response Content
print(response.content)
print(response.headers)

#Parse response to json format
json_response = json.loads(response.text)
print(json_response)

#Fetch value using Json Path
pages = jsonpath.jsonpath(json_response,'total_pages')
print(pages[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code.

```
import requests


with open("list_urls.txt") as f:
    for url in f:
           response = requests.get(url)
           print ("The url is ",url,"and status code is",response.status_code)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it works. Assume a case. I kept all my urls in a file eg: url.list and I want to call that file(url.list) in python script. Is it possible? Because I have more then 100 urls to check. I know how to do it in shell but not in python please help me

Comment: @SameerSheik i have changed the code as per your requirements. list_urls.txt file represents the 100+ urls file. now you can get each url [https status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 0):

You can acess to the status code with response.status_code

You can put your code in a function like this

```py
def treat_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response:
        print('Response OK')
    else:
        print('Response Failed')

    # Display Response Content
    print(response.content)
    print(response.headers)

    #Parse response to json format
    json_response = json.loads(response.text)
    print(json_response)

    #Fetch value using Json Path
    pages = jsonpath.jsonpath(json_response,'total_pages')
    print(pages[0])
```

And have a list of urls and iterate throw it:

```py
url_list=["www.google.com","https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"]
for url in url_list:
    treat_url(url)
```

Comment: Thanks angel it works but my question is how to loop through multiple url's at once let say 100 may be

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions, the question itself is not very clear, so a good articulation would be useful for all the contributors over here :) ...

Now coming to what I was able to comprehend, there are few modifications that you can do:

`response = requests.get(url)` You will always get a response object, I think you might want to check the status code here, which you can do by `response.status_code` and based upon what you get, you say whether or not you got a success response.

and regarding looping, you can check the `last page` from response JSON as `response_json['last_page']` and run a for loop on `range(2, last_page + 1)` and append the page number in URI to fetch individual pages response

You can directly fetch JSON from response object `response.json()`
Please refer to `requests` doc [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/)